# Create Multiplication Table

Tags: python, multiplication

I want to have a Multiplication table... with a given n.
I tried... but my solution does not return what I want!

If n=3
def should return this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
[2, 4, 6, 8],
[3, 6, 9, 12],
[4, 8, 12, 16]]
```

My solution:

```
def multiplication_table(n):
    r=[]
    m = list(list(range(1*i,(n+1)*i, i)) for i in range(1,n+1))
    for i in m:
        i = [str(j).rjust(len(str(m[-1][-1]))+1) for j in i]
        r.append(i)
    return r
n=4
print(multiplication_table(n))
```

But it returns:

```
[[' 1',' 2',' 3',' 4'],
[' 2',' 4',' 6',' 8'],
[' 3',' 6',' 9',' 12'],
[' 4',' 8',' 12',' 16']]
```

It return string in list... but I want int in my list!
I tried other ways but I could not solve this!
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem I guess.

```
def multiplication_table(n):
r=[]
m = list(list(range(1*i,(n+1)*i, i)) for i in range(1,n+1))
for i in m:
    i = [int(str(j).rjust(len(str(m[-1][-1]))+1)) for j in i]
    r.append(i)
return r
```

n=4
print(multiplication_table(n))

Answer (score 0):

```
n = input()   
f = lambda x, n: [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, n**2, n)]
f([x+1 for x in range(n**2)],n)
```

Edited answer:

```
n = input()
x = [i+1 for i in range(n)]
result = []
for i in range(n):
  result.append([j*(i+1) for j in x])
print result
```

Comment: your out put:[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]].....i need [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9, 12], [4, 8, 12, 16]]